# "Syntax Error: Error: No ESLint configuration found in" when I tried to npm run serve a project I got from GitHub

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, eslint

I tried downloading and running a Vue.js project from GitHub that was sent to me, but as soon as I tried `npm run serve`, I got the following error:

```
Syntax Error: Error: No ESLint configuration found in C:\Users\User\Desktop\movies-main\src.
```

I ran `npm install` too beforehand. I've create a couple of Vue.js projects myself and have never had this error so I'm not sure how to solve it. Could I be missing a dependency on my machine or something? I haven't used ESLint before.

Comment: is there a ESlint configuration? this should be a file like `.eslintrc.js `

Comment: @Serg There isn't.

Comment: It means there is not eslint configuration, Check this if you want to set it. https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring/

if you want to disable it check this (You should not in my opinion).
https://github.com/vuejs-templates/webpack/issues/73

Answer (score 8):

Open your project folder. Then run the following command

```
npm install eslint -g -D
```

Then finish by typing :

```
eslint --init
```

Solve the problem for me.

Comment: Can you explain the flags purposes?

Comment: -g global = can be run from the command line anywhere ;  

-D development = if you do install it into a project it will only be there in development not in deployment

Comment: If you don't want to install it globally: npm init @eslint/config

Answer (score 1):

Or use the locally installed `eslint`

```
npm init @eslint/config
```

Answer (score 0):

I was getting this error after symlinking an NPM library via `npm link` in the library directory followed by `npm link <library name>` in the consuming Vue+Vite application.

Vite may be important information because the error stemmed from `vite-plugin-eslint`.

I fixed it by passing in `include` key for the eslint options:

**vite.config.js**

```
import eslint from 'vite-plugin-eslint';
import path from 'path';
// side note: `path` might require node v16+ due to `node:path` import

...

export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [
        eslint({
            // without explicit path resolve, eslint tries to lint external directories symlinked via `npm link`
            include: [
                `${path.resolve(__dirname, '')}/**/*.js`,
                `${path.resolve(__dirname, '')}/**/*.vue`,
            ],
        }),
```

If you look at the docs, you'll see the default `eslint()` with no options passed in (as recommended by their plugin) causes `include: ['**/*.ext'],` so the solution here is to change `**/` to `/explicit/path/to/root/of/your/project/`.

In hypothesis, you could also use the `exclude` key of the eslint options and stop it from trying to lint external folders, but I don't prefer that solution in case of multiple developers because you cannot predict their directory structure.

Answer (score 0):

according to the document of [eslint](https://eslint.org/docs/latest/use/getting-started#quick-start) Open the root of your project then use this command:

```
npm init @eslint/config
```

it will create an `eslintrc`  in the root of the project. this way helped me to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Without installing eslint use **npx**

```
npx eslint --init
```